# Command to print specific column from input

Tags: linux, awk, sed, gnu, multiple-columns

I was wondering if there is some built-in otherwise command available that can print Nth column from input. E.g. `awk '{print $2}'` or `cut...`

It would make life easier when I want to run it on piped output while running it via `ssh` (quoting it always a hell), and of course it'll make life easier in general.

My current hack with a 100 limitations is:

```
function _printcol(){
    while read data; do
        [ -z "$fields" ] && fields=`for num in "$@"; do echo -n "\"\t\",\\$$num"; done`
        echo $data | awk "{ print $fields }"
    done
}
alias printcol=_printcol
ls -ltr | printcol 9
ls -ltr | printcol 1 9
```

I'm wondering if someone already implemented it. I would prefer if it's built-in, or available as widely as possible (like on multiple stock distros) or in the worst case easily installable (like yum, apt, ...).

Comment: Would you list a few of the "100 limitations" that you see with your current function/alias?  (Besides the fact that it could be substantially simplified.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a rewrite

```
printcol() {
    awk -v "fields=$*" '
        BEGIN { n = split(fields, f) }
        {
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
                printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), OFS
            }
            print ""
        }
    '
}

seq 50 | pr -T5 | printcol 2 4 5
```

Notes:

- awk will read the function's stdin: you don't have to capture it and feed it into awk -- advantage: only a single awk invocation, not one per line.
- you don't need to do any gross pre-processing of the field list. Particularly, why are you doing this *inside* the while-loop?
- why are you using a function *and* an alias?

Comment: Thanks! 1) Didn't realize awk inside a function would also read stdin by default; hence the `while read data` loop. 2) the gross thing inside the loop because I read somewhere that `read` must be the first statement in a function if you want to read from stdin. 3) idea was to create one alias per separator/delimiter, unwanted in example I gave.

Comment: Though the correct answer is 'there is no such command', yours was the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted something easy to install.  Just place the following line in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
 printcol() { fields=$(printf '$%i,' "$@"); awk -v OFS='\t' "{ print ${fields%%,} }"; }
```

Invoke it just as you were doing:

```
ls -ltr | printcol 1 9
```